# where to implement IAccelerationListener in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

Hello SO i am developing a game in Android using Andengine in my game i am using IAccelerationListener. i have implemented multiple scene using SceneManager class. but i have one problem

```
"where to use IAccelerationListener"
```

in

```
Level1 extends LScene implements IAccelerationListener
```

or

```
GameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener
```

in Base Activity or in Scene.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: it is a ball moving game like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pickle.mazzter&hl=en and i am using multiple scene for multiple levels

Comment: i want to know which is better to use and why. could some one tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if use `IAccelerationListener` in your `levelscene` then write this

```
public class LevelScene extends Scene implements IAccelerometerListener {

    public LevelScene(YourGameAcitity object) {
        object.getEngine().enableAccelerometerSensor(object, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccelerometerChanged(AccelerometerData pAccelerometerData) {
        System.out.println("X : " + pAccelerometerData.getX());
        System.out.println("Y : " + pAccelerometerData.getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i want to know which is best or better for use.

Comment: if you use AccelerometerData in whole game then 

GameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener is better.

or 

pAccelerometerData  use only one scene then 
Level1 extends LScene implements IAccelerationListener .

for your game 
Level1 extends LScene implements IAccelerationListener is very prefer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use IAccelerationListener in SimpleBaseGameActivity.

GameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IAccelerationListener

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    enableAccelerometerSensor(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    disableAccelerometerSensor();
}
```